# What options are there for storing sensitive data on mobile phones?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am about to develop an app for ios and android using phonegap and sencha touch.
The app will store sensitive data (personal details) so it needs to be protected.
As far as i have read, sencha and phonegap dont have any encryption libraries.
Ideally, i would like to password protect the sql lite database, but i cannot seem to find any mention of whether this is possible.

The only option i have found is to do encryption on the fly using javascript, is this the only option? has anyone else done this? I am curious about how responsive the app would be if it had to encrypt/decrypt everything on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as far as i know there is no mechanism for encryption provided by either sencha or phonegap you need to do encryption on the fly...

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage is encrypted and not available once you close your app.
So you could use SJCL to encrypt your localStorage for runtime.

A better way might be to work with Oauth and request sensible data, when you need them.

But this is not a specific Javascript problem. Once a person has the app, the phone and access to your code this might happen to Android apps.

You can maximize your protection by using a propper whitelisting and https.
Once you build your app for release (not debug), the data are as save as it gets.

Can you point out a screnario where you need more protection?

Worst case would be the wonnabe thief

- has the phone
- runs the app
- can add a script to the app to extract the data